# Batch para apagar vários usuários

Tags: windows, batch, prompt

Boa tarde,
Então, tenho que fazer uma limpa semanalmente em uma maquina que está conectada a um domínio, e deletar todos os usuários (de rede) dela.

Meu plano de ação foi: criar um **Batch** que delete todas as pastas de usuário do **C:\Users** que comecem com "2000", e depois entrasse no **regedit** e apagasse os arquivos residuais dos usuarios no **Computador\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList** para que não tenha problemas caso o usuario que foi apagado logue novamente.

O motivo pelo qual quero apagar somente as pastas que comecem com 2000, é que desse jeito não iria apagar a minha pasta de usuário (que no caso começa com 1040). segue a dir da pasta para ter uma noção melhor.

```
 Pasta de C:\Users

13/11/2019  14:58    <DIR>          .
13/11/2019  14:58    <DIR>          ..
03/12/2019  11:54    <DIR>          10202089
09/01/2020  14:44    <DIR>          10401794
25/10/2019  15:13    <DIR>          20005500
13/11/2019  15:59    <DIR>          20006093
25/10/2019  15:13    <DIR>          20006253
25/10/2019  15:13    <DIR>          20006421
```

Estou tendo dificuldades de fazer essa condicional no script Batch, não consigo achar uma maneira de apagar somente estas pastas em especifico (as que começam com "2000"), **alguém poderia me ajudar a criar um condicional para este caso?**

(caso tenha algum outro método que eu possa aplicar favor me dizer)

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a ajuda for muito simples ainda é possível fazer nos comentários.